# FutureBuilder does not get into builder?

Tags: flutter, flutter-onpressed

I want to get two parameters from createUser response. 
I have a raisedbutton and i want to use FutureBuilder when onPressed.
future property works well, but i can not get in builder property. I tried everything but i could not find solution.

```
...
RaisedButton(
        elevation: 5.0,
        onPressed: (){
          FutureBuilder(
              future: createUser(usernameController.text, emailController.text, passwordController.text, '1', 1),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasData) {
                  saveLogin(snapshot.data.userUnique);
                  nextScreen(
                      context,
                      UserDetail(
                        userUnique: snapshot.data.userUnique,
                      ));
                } else {
                  return MyHomePage();
                }
                return MyHomePage();
              });
        },
...


Future createUser(String username, String password, String email,
    String logintype, int userUnique) async {
  String url =
      "http://api.xx.com/api/register?username=$username&password=$password&email=$email&logintype=$logintype&userUnique=$userUnique";

  final response =
      await http.get(url, headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
  return registerFromJson(utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes));
```

Comment: FutureBuilder is a widget and I don't think it's what you want here. I think you need to take the future here and use async/await or .then((){}) on that future. Putting a widget inside the onPressed method doesn't do anything and it doesn't really make sense

Comment: I want to get two parameters from createUser response that why i use futurebuilder after onpressed.

Comment: you need to Navigate to other classes if that's what you aiming for here like   Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage()),
  );

Comment: @MousaAlribi there is no problem navigate to other class. I want to decide navigate after createUser method response.

Comment: don't use futurebuild try to Await createUser and put everything you want to do after it .. it will not run until you get the creatuser returns

Comment: @MousaAlribi, how to handle createUser responseCode and userUnique could you please give me some code example.

Comment: what do you want to do with your `FutureBuilder` which is not attached to any parent widget? i mean there is no: `SomeParentWidget(child: FutureBuilder(...))`

Comment: @pskink I have a method " createUser " and this method returns two parameter(responseCode and userUnique). I try to navigate page according to responseCode. Thats it.

Comment: so use `Future.then()` or `async` / `await`, more: https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await - as i said your `FutureBuilder` hangs in the air: it is not attached to any parent widget

Comment: `createUser(usernameController.text, emailController.text, passwordController.text, '1', 1).then((value) => print(value));`

Comment: @pskink if i use async / await, how to handle userUnique and responseCode from my method.

Comment: use .then it will return the values from your function and you can handle it as you like

Comment: your method cannot return two `Future`s - it returns one `Future<SomeClass>` - most likely `Future<User>` or something like that - you did not post `createUser()` method code so i can only guess...

Comment: @pskink i updated my code. You can see my createUser method.

Comment: so it returns `registerFromJson(...)`

Comment: @pskink registerFromJson has responseCode and userUnique properties.

Answer (score 2):

I changed FutureBuilder to async / await method

thanks for your help @pskink

```
onPressed: () async {
                            var xx = await createUser( usernameController.text, emailController.text, passwordController.text, '1',userUnique());
                            print(xx.responseCode.toString());
                            print(xx.userUnique.toString());
                            saveLogin(userUnique());

                          },
```